# insert pdf file as image in given excel worksheet

Tags: image, excel, vba, pdf

I have been trying to modify this script to take the pdf file and insert it as an image into the active worksheet.  but it keeps creating a new workbook and inserting into the new book.

Can someone help me modify this script so it inserts the pdf as an image to the worksheet called "report".

Sub insert_pdf_to_report()

Dim Xl
Dim Wb
Dim Ws
Dim Ol

```
Sheets("Report").Activate

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Wb = Xl.Workbooks.Add
Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets.Add
Set Ol = Ws.OLEObjects.Add(, "C:\QGC_HSSE\template.pdf", True, False)

    With Ol
        .Left = Ws.Range("A1").Left
        .Height = Ws.Range("A1").Height
        .Width = Ws.Range("A1").Width
        .Top = Ws.Range("A1").Top
    End With

    Sheets("Report").Activate
Xl.Visible = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Sheets("Report").Activate

Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
Set Ol = Ws.OLEObjects.Add(, "/Users/tcan/Farewell-dinner.jpg", True, False)

...
```

The problem with your code is that these statements:

```
Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Wb = Xl.Workbooks.Add
Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets.Add
```

create a new workbook and a worksheet inside the new WB.

I do not have excel to test this but I think my code may work as your expectation by removing the commands that create new workbook.

Cheers.

Comment: This worked thanks, however it causes a concern with the OLE Object not closing the file so on repeat of the code the PDf get locked and the image appears blank.  I have written a script to support the unlock of the file to prevent the blank object being inserted if the macro is run repeatedly.